# What would prevent capybara/selenium from hovering over a visible element?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am writing automation tests for a webpage. I can't share any specific details, so all I'm looking for is some general brain-storming to help me figure out what is causing the problem. A long-shot, I know, but I've become obsessed with this problem.

There is an element with id="troublesome" on the webpage. On manual testing, hovering over #troublesome will cause it to disappear and something else pops up in its place (as it should). I'm trying to verify that the pop-up occurs on hover using automation testing (Capybara, selenium driver, ruby). However, no matter what technique I use, hovering doesn't work.

## troublesome is visible upon visiting the page. It is not cut off by screen size. Capybara has no trouble finding it and reading its text and attributes. i.e. A regular ol' find("#troublesome").text will return the correct text.

However, I cannot use Capybara to click on #troublesome without executing javascript.

i.e. find("#troublesome").click won't do anything (it won't throw any errors either). I must use find("#troublesome").execute_script("this.click()") to click on it.

But I don't need to click it. I just need to hover over it.

**Using Capybara:**

find("#troublesome").hover --> will not work. No errors thrown either. Test just continues until it fails because it fails to find the expected result. Telling ruby to sleep(however_many_seconds) doesn't help.

**Using Selenium:**

page.driver.browser.action.move_to(find("#troublesome").native).perform --> this doesn't work either. Again, no errors thrown.

**Using trigger:**

find("#troublesome").trigger(:mouseover) --> doesn't work because selenium driver doesn't support trigger (and I don't want to use another driver).

**Using jquery:**

Won't work. Website doesn't use jquery

**Attempting to use javascript to force :hover to be true on element doesn't work:**

mouseHover = 'var x = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
x.initMouseEvent("mouseover", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementById("troublesome").dispatchEvent(x);'

page.execute_script(mouseHover)

(I can change mouseOver to click, and it'll click though!)
Apparently, mouseover is not 'trusted' by browser (but click is), so kinda useless to have that as an option, isn't it?

I've tried all of the above by working within a within("#id") do... end block. Doesn't make a difference.

**I've even tried unconventional means to get the mouse over #troublesome:**

find("#troublesome").right_click --> the mouse will be DIRECTLY over #troublesome, right-click, and a menu will pop up RIGHT OVER the element!!!!!!

So CLEARLY, the mouse IS hovering over #troublesome during my automation test, yet it's not registering on the browser. The website is not bugged. Hovering works when I do it manually.

I can find other elements on the webpage and hover over them just fine. In fact, I've even tried putting the mouse over another element, then moving it from there to #troublesome like so:

page.driver.browser.action.move_to(find("#somethingElse").native, 1200, -50).perform

That doesn't work, but if I adjust the coordinates to a third element just below #somethingElse, this will trigger the third element's hover state, so clearly this strategy can work in principle and practice, yet not for #troublesome!

Note that #somethingElse and the 'third element' exist on a div that is at the same 'heirarchy' as the ancestor div of #troublesome.

There are iframes on the webpage, but #troublesome is not on the iframe.

There are random script tags inserted all over the body of the webpage. I don't know what those script tags are doing as I can't see the code.

**#troublesome has become my Moby Dick.**

This whale is driving me nuts. I've invested too much time into it already. I can't give up now or all those hours of toil would be for nothing.

Please help.

Thank you.

find("#troublesome").hover

page.driver.browser.action.move_to(find("#troublesome").native).perform

find("#troublesome").trigger(:mouseover)

mouseHover = 'var x = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
x.initMouseEvent("mouseover", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementById("myDiv").dispatchEvent(x);'

page.execute_script(mouseHover)

page.driver.browser.action.move_to(find("#somethingElse").native, 1200, -50).perform

No error messages other than standard capybara/rspec failure log because it failed to find the element that was supposed to pop up upon hovering over #troublesome

Comment: Just for the sake of experiment, try to use another driver such as `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`. If you case will work with `page.find('#element').trigger(:mouseover)` then you know the issue is from Selenium and can report it to the project.

Comment: Do you know what events the page is using to trigger the behavior you expect?

Comment: @achempion - Yes. I should try using another driver. I won't be able to use it for the final test file as it's not what the team uses, but at least I can know if the problem is the driver.

Comment: @Thomas Walpole - It's just a simple :hover event specified in css  styles.

Comment: Selenium with chrome definitely does support hovering that will work with CSS :hover as shown by https://gist.github.com/twalpole/f13bea888fdbd58bf70924fa3f5e9031.  If you can modify that gist to show the behavior you're seeing then I can probably provide a solution.  Note: triggering events by JS will never make CSS :hover work, it would only possibly work if the code was dependent on the specific events being triggered. Is it possible there are multiple sequential hovers that have to happen for the CSS to behave as desired?

Comment: @Thomas Walpole - I can replicate the html for just the relevant elements which can then be inserted into the template html:

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="next">Next</div>
      <div id="preview"><img src="https://www.whatever.com"></div>
</div>

Comment: In styles, it's the parent 'wrapper' that detects the hover, which then triggers the child elements 'next' and 'preview' to appear (opacity from 0 to 1). The parent wrapper's z-index is set to some ridiculously high number, presumably to force it to the very top layer so that it'll detect a mouse hover on itself and its children elements. I'm not sure if maybe Selenium isn't able to hover over the parent element because the child element is right on top of it (and completely covers it). Though, any hover over the child element should count as a hover over the parent element, right?

Comment: Other than the highly simplified html I provided to illustrate what I'm seeing, there are a bunch of script tags in the body. I don't know what they do or how I can find them even if I could look into the repo. The hover itself is definitely just CSS:hover and nothing more fancy than that.

Comment: @Thomas Walpole - I've narrowed down the problem to an iframe. Basically, I copied the entire <body> of the html and put it on glitch. I removed each main element within the <body> 1 by 1 until I was able to get the hover to work. By removing an iframe (which covers the whole screen), the hover worked. I don't know why this is the case. The hover element itself is not within the iframe (it's in the main document). Furthermore, it's z-index is set to a ridiculously high number so that it is on top of the iframe, not hidden by the iframe. I still don't know what the solution is, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is because the '.hoverme' element in your example at https://jsfiddle.net/pwo7zuL2/1/ has a size of 0x0 px (this is also why you couldn't click it).  The size is 0x0 because it only contains absolute positioned elements which don't technically count when calculating the auto size of the parent. If instead of attempting to hover over the .hoverme element you hover over the visible absolute positioned child (which actually has size) of the element the hover will work correctly (which is what you are actually doing when you do it manually in your example).

```
find('#next').hover
```

Comment: Yes. As per my bug report to selenium github, I mentioned that I tried find('#next').hover. This didn't work even though the child element has size and is visible.

Comment: @Doggo - Works fine with your example - https://gist.github.com/twalpole/e081df8a3d9ebe52136c8d2593a96006

Comment: if you do manage to get 

find('#next').hover 

to work with capybara+selenium, let me know. I wouldn't use the jsfiddle to do the testing as I think it puts everything into a frame which further complicates the html (unless there's a way to get to the page directly that I don't know of). What I used to test the mock-up of the actual webpage I was testing was glitch-me. Any equivalent free-hosting service should do.

And also thank you for taking the time to look into this problem of mine. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I looked at your github where you cloned the html document. I noticed that the iframe doesn't have an 'src' specified

i.e. <iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>

WHen I tested with no src, the hover works. Try putting wikipedia into the "src". If I do that, the hover no longer works (using selenium) but still does manually. Thanks

Comment: You don’t need to use glitchme to test anything just run the gist I linked to with ruby, it’ll start up a server and serve the HTML at the bottom to the browser

Comment: I updated the gist to put the src back -- still works fine (`ruby test_hover_child.rb') with both headless and headful chrome via selenium

Comment: I ran your gist file directly, and the hover works. It must be something specific about the environment I'm running my tests in vs the environment you're using. For one, I'm not using gem 'puma' to serve up the html using my own machine. 

Thanks for your input. I'll look into tweaking my test environment to see what's causing the hover failure.

Answer (score 0):

I now know the problem, and I have a solution (albeit a hacky one).

The problem is due to an iframe which covers the full screen. This blocks selenium from being able to hover over #troublesome even though #troublesome is not within the iframe and #troublesome's z-index is set to a high number (thereby forcing it to be at the top layer).

Manual hovering works, but hovering with selenium fails. I believe this is a bug, so I have reported it on selenium's github.

One solution that works is to use javascript to force the iframe to shrink, then hover (which should work now), then use javascript to return the iframe to full screen (so as to not affect other aspects of the test).

shrink_frame = 'document.getElementById("#frame").setAttribute("style", "width: 100px; height 100px");'

page.execute_script(shrink_frame)

This is not an ideal solution because it is obviously not how a real user would interact with the webpage, but it's acceptable given that this is due to a selenium bug and that manual testing works.